# Swagger generated JAX-RS server breaks with ElasticSearch dependency

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, jetty, swagger

I have generated JAX-RS server code with [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) which runs with the following command:

```
mvn clean package jetty:run
```

Now, the purpose of the server is, among other things, to index POST requests in ElasticSearch. However, adding [elastic search high level rest client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client) in the pom makes the server break on start. See Error message at bottom.

I want to add that I'm actually importing another project into the server as a maven dependency, that's where I first encountered the error, because the other project has elasticsearch as a dependency. I narrowed it down and it turns out everything works fine without the elasticsearch dependency. Adding elasticsearch depency in the server pom directly gives the same error so that's where the issue must lie.

I've tried with multiple versions of elasticsearch, no difference.

I will also attach the contents of the POM file at the bottom.

Maven dependency tree attached at the bottom.

Following the advice of Joakim Erdfelt I've tried changing javax-servlet to version 3.1 and Jetty 9.2.28.v20190418. The problem persists but with new error message, se bottom.

Original error Message:

> Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@29c53c4f{/,file:/home/administrator/Documents/company/projects/gefion/repos/gefmail-db/jaxrs-server/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/home/administrator/Documents/company/projects/gefion/repos/gefmail-db/jaxrs-server/src/main/webapp/}
>
> **org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions**
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations (AnnotationConfiguration.java:536)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure (AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure (WebAppContext.java:479)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1337)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:741)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:505)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:387)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:354)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart (JettyServer.java:73)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:167)
>
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
>
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
>
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)

original pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>swagger-jaxrs-server</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Unlicense</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <webAppSourceDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
          <stopPort>8079</stopPort>
          <stopKey>stopit</stopKey>
          <stopWait>10</stopWait>
          <httpConnector>
            <port>8080</port>
            <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
          </httpConnector>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/gen/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>${logback-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Base64 encoding that works in both JVM and Android -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
      <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <swagger-core-version>1.5.18</swagger-core-version>
    <jetty-version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty-version>
    <jersey2-version>2.22.2</jersey2-version>
    <jackson-version>2.8.9</jackson-version>
    <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
    <logback-version>1.1.7</logback-version>
    <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs-server:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-geo:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:aggs-matrix-stats-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.20:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.8.9:compile

[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.brsanthu:migbase64:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
```

Error message with changed versions:
javax-servlet version 3.1
Jetty 9.2.28.v20190418

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations (AnnotationConfiguration.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure (AnnotationConfiguration.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure (WebAppContext.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart (JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/elasticsearch/core/internal/io/Streams.class from jar file:/home/administrator/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-core/7.0.0/elasticsearch-core-7.0.0.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass (AnnotationParser.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry (AnnotationParser.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you show your maven dependency of ES?

Comment: I've added the entire POM file

Comment: You've cut off the full stacktrace just before the details, since it's a `MultiException` there will be many more parts, usually indicated as "suppressed" or "caused by" which give you the details on what went wrong.   Can you edit your question and include all of the stacktraces please?

Comment: Jetty 9.2.9.v20150224 is rather old, have you considered using something more current? (like version `9.2.28.v20190418`?).  Jetty 9.x is also Servlet 3.1 (not Servlet 2.5 like you have in your pom).

Comment: Can you run `$ mvn dependency:tree` and include the output in your question?

Comment: I've added the dependency tree just now, watch the LATEST edit.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I've pasted all the details, there is no additional parts suppressed or caused by...

Answer (score 0):

The cause ...

```
Error scanning entry 
META-INF/versions/9/org/elasticsearch/core/internal/io/Streams.class
from jar file:/home/administrator/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-core/7.0.0/elasticsearch-core-7.0.0.jar
```

... is telling you that you have a JEP-238 Multi-Release JAR file present in your project.

The first version of Jetty to support JEP-238 Multi-Release JAR files was Jetty 9.4.9.

See past questions (and answers on this topic):

- [Error scanning entry "module-info.class" when starting Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311295/error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-when-starting-jetty-server)
- [Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716306/failed-startup-of-context-c-g-g-d-s-j-webappcontextwithreload)
- [Bytecode Scanning error on META-INF/versions/9/* and Elasticsearch 6.2.2+ with Jetty 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956562/bytecode-scanning-error-on-meta-inf-versions-9-and-elasticsearch-6-2-2-with-j)

Comment: Changing to Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320 results in build failure: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.9.v20180320:run (default-cli) on project swagger-jaxrs-server: Not war packaging -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.9.v20180320:run (default-cli) on project swagger-jaxrs-server: Not war packaging
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: `jetty-maven-plugin:run` is for `<packaging>war</packaging>`.   You would not use that goal with a `<packaging>jar</packaging>` project (like yours).   There's no webapp for that plugin to "run".   Old versions of Jetty would just quietly do nothing.  New versions of Jetty tell you why it's inappropriate.

Comment: And maven project that has a `src/main/webapp` should be a declared as `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

Comment: Considering all this code is autogenerated by Swagger I haven't made any active choices regarding the configuration of the pom file. I don't know how should proceed since I'm new to server development.